# Project Euler #5 in Ruby - Code Result Unexpected

Tags: ruby

Apologies for asking such a narrow question. I am trying to solve problem 5 from Project Euler (Computes the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20) to learn Ruby.

I wrote the following code:

```
def calc_min_multiple(array)
     array.each do |value|
         if div_check(value) == true
           return value
           break
         end
     end
end


def div_check(num)
  1.upto(20) do |divisor|
     if num % divisor != 0
        return false
     end
  end  
    return true
end

range = *(20..500000)
puts calc_min_multiple(range)
```

The weird thing is that the program just puts every value in the range array I define, without going through all the logic inside the functions. I tried debugging but could not find the issue. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please do be explicit in what your question is.  This entire thing was a statement.  It helps if we can figure out if you are trying to get a solution for the challenge, or if you are asking about a specific thing.  In this case, I chose that you wanted to know about why your Array is being returned when you give .each a block.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question "Why does my method come back and return the Array I gave it?" is due to what the documentation states about [`each` when you give a block.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each).  That array is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am still a bit confused about each vs. map. It seems like in both cases each value in the array is evaluated by the code in turn.

Comment: That is true.  They do both iterate.  However, one returns the collection acted on, the other collects results, returning a new array.  The documentation is clear on this. As stated in the map documentation: "Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block."

Comment: There is a *"lot of fundamental misunderstanding"* displayed in your answer as well. Most of it is nonsense. The suggestion to use `map` is worthless, as the point is to find the *first* number for which `div_check` returns `true`, not to return a list of numbers. And the `div_check` method is essentially doing `(1..20).all? { |divisor| num % divisor == 0 }`: your proposed `check_num` alternative doesn't help at all, as it checks only a single divisor.

Comment: @vgoff: I'm sorry, but *most* of your post is nothing to do with the reason for `calc_min_multiple` returning an array. Using `map` instead of `each` will make no difference at all; it is irrelevant that the `break` is unreachable; and I can't fathom what you meant by your `check_num` method, unless you are proposing a *third* method that is called by `div_check`. The only useful thing you say is in the penultimate paragraph. I hope downvoting my own answer helped you to feel better.

Comment: You do fathom the check though, you use it directly in your block code.  Not as a method of course, as that may be silly (not to mention inefficient and the check is very clear on its own) but you do fathom the use of it.  The rest of the post was intended to refactor the code and get rid of code written that never gets reached, does not read well.  And you now show that journey well, and have no problem upvoting it based on that. My use of map neglected to state to not use the return, but only the break.  Poor communication on my part.  Removed it.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems in `calc_min_mulitple` method

1. `div_check(value) == true`. Though it'll work you don't check boolean equality like this. Simply do `if div_check(value)` for `true` or `if !div_check(value)` for `false`.
2. In the `array.each` block `break` statement is unreachable because you `return false` before it.

Comment: `if !div_check(value)` is *much* better written `unless div_check(value)`

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are hitting is because your code doesn't try a high enough number to satisfy the criterion. (Hint: it's way over 1E8, and it will take *ages* to calculate this way, which is why it's on Project Euler!)

When the loop in `calc_min_multiple` terminates at the end of the array, it returns the last expression evaluated which is the `each`, which evaluates to the array it was acting on, so your `puts` just prints *all* of the array elements.

So you need a specific `return` in the `calc_min_multiple` method to say that no results were found.

Another point. Rather than building a half-million element array, a Ruby `range` has an `each` method too, so you can just pass the (unflattened) range.

You can also use the post-fixed statement modifier `if` usefully here, so your methods look like this

```
def calc_min_multiple(range)
  range.each do |value|
    return value if div_check(value)
  end
  'None'
end

def div_check(num)
  1.upto(20) do |divisor|
    return false if num % divisor != 0
  end
  return true
end

puts calc_min_multiple(20..500_000)
```

**output**

```
None
```

Finally, a more Rubyish way of doing this:

```
def calc_min_multiple(range)
  range.find { |value| div_check(value) }
end

def div_check(num)
  (1..20).all? { |divisor| num % divisor == 0 }
end

puts calc_min_multiple(20..500_000)
```